# couchbase client for PHP in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, couchbase

I am using Ubuntu14.04 and run PHP on it. Now I want the PHP to connect to Couchbase. However, I searched google and cannot find any suitable client for Ubuntu 14.04 of Couchbase Client. Does anyone have the idea to use the couchbase for php in Ubuntu 14.04/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using Ubuntu 14.04, Paddy's solution did not work,
these rewritten commands did work:

```
wget -O- http://packages.couchbase.com/ubuntu/couchbase.key | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://packages.couchbase.com/ubuntu trusty trusty/main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/couchbase.list
apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libcouchbase2-core libcouchbase2-libevent libcouchbase-dev
```

`-` missing after `apt-key add`, source file is missing a file ending, Ubuntu Aptitude only parses `sources.list.d/*.list`, `libcouchbase-devel` got renamed to `libcouchbase-dev`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need to install Libcouchbase (LCB):

```
wget -O- http://packages.couchbase.com/ubuntu/couchbase.key | sudo apt-key add
echo "deb http://packages.couchbase.com/ubuntu trusty trusty/main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/couchbase
apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libcouchbase2-core libcouchbase2-libevent libcouchbase-devel
```

The [Couchbase documentation](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/c-2.4/download-install.html) covers this in more detail.

Once LCB has been installed then you will need to install the Couchbase PHP SDK:

```
pecl install couchbase
```

Again the [Couchbase documentation](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/php-2.0/download-install.html) covers this in more detail.